# VB.NET Search website for text and put into textbox1.text

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I'm trying to search a website for a specific phrase, and then add that phrase to `textbox.text`.

This is the code I have right now, but it's not working:

```
 Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.GetAttribute("classname") = "alert alert-warning ng-binding ng-scope" Then
            If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("No Flex Visit could be found.") Then
                txtMessage.Text = curElement.InnerText
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next
```

URL snippet of what I need to grab:

```html
<div ng-controller="FlexVisitController" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngInclude: '/ng/flexVisit/views/flexVisitListView.htm?201612080346' -->
<div ng-include="'/ng/flexVisit/views/flexVisitListView.htm?201612080346'" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngIf: flexVisitList.length == 0 -->
<div class="alert alert-warning ng-binding ng-scope" role="alert" ng-if="flexVisitList.length == 0">
 No Flex Visit could be found.
</div>
<!-- end ngIf: flexVisitList.length == 0 -->
<!-- ngRepeat: project in flexVisitList -->
</div>
```

So, what the URL above says is if `flexVisitList` is `0` then display message: "No Flex Visit could be found."

What im trying to accomplish is if this message is on the website then add to a text box.

Thanks

Chad

Comment: Check `curElement.GetAttribute("classname")`, use `class` instead of `classname` or use only `alert`, `alert-warning`... etc as its value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you said, but with no luck. I added a Label6.text = " Step 1" in the stepping, to see if it gets that far and it is not getting passed the 'if class name' step.